# media folder images are not displaying in Template Page

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm new to Django. Medial folder images are not displaying in Template file. please help me in that.

models.py

```
class Images(models.Model):
    image = models. ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True, null=True)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
......
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py

```
def image_display(request):
    image_obj = Images.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'image_obj': image_obj})
```

index.html

```
<body>

    {% for item in myoffers_objs %}
    <div>
        <img src="{{ item.image.url }}" alt="Images"/>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

</body>
```

[Project details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcQRz.png) where i did mistake. why its displaying like this.
[Image displaying like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojkoH.png)

Answer (score 0):

The for loop in the template file is incorrect.
Try this

```html
<body>

    {% for item in image_obj %}
    <div>
        <img src="{{ item.image.url }}" alt="Images"/>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

</body>
```

Comment: Sorry my bad. I changed that but it's showing same it's not displaying.

Comment: Run a migrate, check if the file actually uploaded to the media folder, clear and reupload the file.

Comment: You can not show media files in template ? or django can not serve media files at all ?

Comment: sorry my bad. Thanks for the help now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

correct static_root:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

you have to add this to your html file if you use statics in that html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

also you have to run this command to collect static files in your project:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```